# Why am i getting an error hip: bitstream problem, resyncing skipping while playing mp3 songs?

Tags: c++, c, mp3, id3-tag

I am getting an error of bitsream problem. I am already skipping reading of id3tag by 512 bytes, but still I am not able to play all songs while some songs are getting played

```
define MP3_SKIP_SIZE  512
fseek(playerDetails->mp3Fp,MP3_SKIP_SIZE,SEEK_SET);
```

Answer (score 1):

Size of ID3 tags is variable, it is not neccessarily 512 bytes.

You can use [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) to find out size of ID3 tags:

```cpp
#include <id3/tag.h>

// Get size of ID3 tags 

size_t getID3TagSize(const char* filename)
{
    ID3_Tag myTag(filename);

    return myTag.Size();
}



#include <lame.h>

void decodeMp3(const char* fileName)
{
    size_t mp3TagSize = getID3TagSize(fileName);

    f.open(fileName, std::ios::binary);

    f.seekg(mp3TagSize); //Skip ID3 tags

    std::array<unsigned char, 1024*1024> buffer;

    f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer[0]), buffer.size());

    auto count = f.gcount();

    hip_t lameInput = hip_decode_init();

    mp3data_struct mp3data{ 0 };

    std::array<short, 1024 * 1024 * 8> pcm_l;
    std::array<short, 1024 * 1024 * 8> pcm_r;

    int decodeResult = hip_decode_headers(lameInput, &buffer[0], count, &pcm_l[0], &pcm_r[0], &mp3data);


    //... Continue decoding ...

}
```